# Can I identify encrypted files resulting in dmesg errors, or fsck the encrypted files?

Tags: 11.10, ecryptfs, dmesg

A few days ago, I accidentally ran out of space in my encrypted (ecryptfs) home folder after upgrading to oneiric (Tracker went nuts). I noticed because I couldn't write my files with vim anymore, and one actually got zeroed-out. However, the problem is that now I'm seeing errors in my dmesg:

```
[ 4243.291883] Valid eCryptfs headers not found in file header region or xattr region
[ 4243.291888] Either the lower file is not in a valid eCryptfs format, or the key could not be retrieved. Plaintext passthrough mode is not enabled; returning -EIO
```

So my questions are:

- Should I be really concerned about these messages?
- Is there any way to identify **which files** are the cause of these errors?
- Alternatively, is there any way to do a check of the entire ecryptfs folder to check for inconsistencies?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well know bug see [Here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ecryptfs-utils/+bug/372014) see message #21

WORKAROUND :

**Dustin Kirkland (kirkland) wrote on 2010-01-05:   #21**

Comment: Thanks. I deleted some ~100 empty files reported unused by fuser and the messages are now gone. Thanks!